# Is "delete" a hyponym of "edit"?

Tags: verbs, hypernyms, programming, computing

In computer science, is *delete* considered to be included in *edit*, or are they two separate things?

Example: Editing item details and deleting items.

In my case, both can be done by the same user and from the same place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming, which is expressly proscribed in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deletion certainly alters an item (whether in computer science, or otherwise), and so covers an subset of the set of actions covered by *edit*, and so could obviously be considered a hyponym of *delete*.

In computer science in particular, permissions may often be stricter on deletion than editing (e.g. anyone who can delete can edit, but not everyone who can edit can delete). Which would encourage this view.

However, in computer science it is certainly possible to have the opposite position, especially when it pertains to personal data (e.g. an admin has the right to remove a user, but not to change their profile as that would make it look like the user was saying something and hence have different legal repercussions). Hence not a hyponym.

Outside of computer science, the implication of "I edited the document" does not generally cover the possibility that I deleted it (hence not hyponym).

However, if I said, "I edited the document to make it better", and then showed you a blank page, then I might be seen as making a statement that was technically correct, albeit unusual, for an effect of humour. Hence, a hyponym "strictly", but not in the most obvious meanings.

Which we get quite a bit in English; a word "strictly speaking" covers certain cases, but generally isn't taken to, and it's a hypernym of that other case or not depending on which way you take it.

When we come back to computer science, the word can be found applied sometimes one way, and sometimes the other way, to the system being discussed. It might even be both in the same system at different layers (e.g. one layer has different rights for altering and deleting records, but that below treats deleting as a sort of altering).

So in all therefore, the answer is "sometimes".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it depends on the context. In contexts with finely grained permissions, it might be surprising if deletion were considered a subset of editing. On the other hand, if there are only two permissions, e.g. "view-only" and "editor", then it would be more natural to expect "edit" privileges to include deletion.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete some content within an item, it would be considered as editing the item.

If you delete the item itself, it would be more drastic than editing, so you would normally need higher privilege rights to be able to delete an item than for editing it. In some settings this would not apply, but it is the general rule.

Answer (score 0):

Normally , Delete is associated strictly with deleting records or anything. Whereas Edit is associated with updates of entry, privileges, at times there may be some delete option witin 'edit', but it may be ambiguous at times, function-wise. It is best to use them differently to keep things clear.